# virtualhost *:443 vs virtualhost ip:443 for apache ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ip, virtualhost

i had a virtual host config for ssl in apache as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/home/user/Documents/Development/oshackers-developers/website/"
ServerName oshackers.org
```

this config never worked. Apache show up the default page of /var/www

When i changed the config to next lines

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.3:443>
DocumentRoot "/home/user/Documents/Development/oshackers-developers/website/"
ServerName oshackers.org
```

apache worked and i had access to my ssl site.

why ssl needs an ip to work and cannot work for any site ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have name-based virtual hosts enabled with the `NameVirtualHost` directive, then the `<VirtualHost>` directive must match the `NameVirtualHost` directive in order for apache to serve the correct content.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like there's already another `*:443` listener in place serving `/var/www` but no `NameVirtualHost *:443` configured.

Comment: yes you are right! There was no NameVirtualHost *:443 after enabled mod_ssl. i had to write this line in /etc/apache2/ports.conf. Now it is working.

Comment: You should accept the answer (the checkmark next to the post) since that fixed it.